# LaTeX Error: Command \ifnumber already defined with the use of nomenclature

Tags: errors, nomenclature, nomencl

I am having issues getting my nomenclature package to show when I compile. After some searching I believe that there might be some package-interference. I have tried looking in the `output.log` file, but that did not make any wiser. See attached snapshot of log-file and a few lines before the error.

Note: I don't have any KOMA-package in my preamble or know what that is. If it helps I am using Overleaf and PdfLaTeX as compiler.

The following two errors appear after including only `\usepackage{nomencl}`:

> LaTeX Error: Command \ifnumber already defined.
>
> LaTeX Error: Command \test@number already defined.

Appreciate any help!

EDIT: No errors after loading `\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}` after `\usepackage{nomencl}`, but the nomenclature is still not printed.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings} % for script
\usepackage[framed, numbered]{mcode} % for MATLAB-script
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % If you write in English
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
    \setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)},aysep{,}}
    %plainnat
    %abbrvnat Harvard?
    %babunsrt
    %agsm - Harvard
    %humannat
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{nomencl} %For abbrevations
    \makenomenclature
    % \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
    % \renewcommand{\nompreamble}{The next list describes several symbols that will be later used within the body of the document}
    % \immediate\write18{%
    % makeindex main.nlo -s abbr.ist -o main.nls%
    % } 
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \definecolor{dgreen}{RGB}{0,150,0}
    \definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{0,0,180}
    % \usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=dblue]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
          colorlinks = true,
          linkcolor = black,
          anchorcolor = black,
          citecolor = black,
          urlcolor = blue
    }
    %Add prefix to hyperref
    \addto\extrasenglish{%
      \def\subsubsectionautorefname{}%
      \def\subsectionautorefname{}%
      \def\figureautorefname{Figure}
      \def\tableautorefname{Table}%
      \def\sectionautorefname{Section}%
    }

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    % backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    % commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    % keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    % numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    % stringstyle=\color{magenta},
    % captionpos=b,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,  
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Vedlegg}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}

\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par%
    }
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}

\begin{document}
\input{01_Input/Chapter_input.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no `nomenclature` package in CTAN (I assume you are using a renamed version of `nomencl`, from the packages it loads). Please show us a compilable example that demostrates this issue.

Comment: nomencl loads tocbasic (which is part of KOMA). But the main question is which package defines \ifnumber before this. So showing your package list would be very helpful.

Comment: I have added the package list as of now

Comment: @campa, thank you. Reversing the order has solved the compiling errors, but the nomenclature is still not printed
```
\nomenclature{NLP}{Natural Language Processing}
\printnomenclature
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs also with the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

The reason is that `babelbib` defines `\ifnumber` in the same way as KoMa-Script classes (more precisely, the package `scrbase`) do. In order to avoid troubles when using one of these classes `babelbib` uses `\providecommand`.

The trouble is, newer versions of `nomencl` load `tocbasic`, which loads `scrbase`, which has `\newcommand{\ifnumber}`, and the damage is there. Luckily there is a very simple solution: swap the order of these two packages

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{babelbib}
```

In this way `\ifnumber` is defined when `nomencl` is loaded, and since `babelbib` uses `\providecommand` it will do nothing.

Comment: thank you. Reversing the order has solved the compiling errors, but the nomenclature is still not printed 
``` \nomenclature{NLP}{Natural Language Processing} 
\printnomenclature ```